# asp.net mvc webservice, how to call from widowsforms application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

I have a task to automate  sending zipped file with serialized data from window application to web application, and there is my problem i don't know how exactly do this, can I from window app send zipped file to controller action which would accept that file and unzip it? Probably this files will be large and i know if do this by ftp server or asp.net mvc (as webservice)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC has nothing to do with web services, to my knowledge, though I suppose you could fake it.

Why not use WCF, which is *meant* for web services?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think webservices handle binary data very well. I believe it has to be encoded in order to transfer which can increase the transfer size significantly. I'd recommend a hybrid solution.

Create a webservice which returns a ticket ID for the requested file. Pass the ticket ID to a URL to download your file using HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a binary data but some data in xml (lot of xml). The problem is: someone is locally adding some records to local database and the some of that data want to upload to website , and my problem is how to implement that export/import?